# Splitting string for different hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td class="h4">               
           <a href="../DiseaseDescription.aspx?DiseaseName=<%#:Item.DiseaseAssociated %>"><%#:Item.DiseaseAssociated %></a>
        </td>
     </tr>
   <table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I have a Entity class called Animals which has diseaseAssociated member.  This member will contain diseases like Dourine, Rabies, Distemper as one string. Now the table will show these disease in a string format. But i want it get split so that when clicked on individual disease, it goes to its respective pages where the disease can be described.

Beside that, I have Disease Entity Class which has DiseaseName, DiseaseDescrition members.

for example, (Dourine, Rabies, Distemper) instead of one string, should be splitted by comma and then i can chose only Rabies and move to DiseaseDescrition page and provide information of Rabies.

Comment: It's a bit annoying to do it inline, but you can just split the string and then join it into multiple links. Alternately, you could create a property or function for the class that generates the links for you. Or you could add a repeating element in your template and bind to it after you split. Or...

Comment: How about using a ternary operator in your inline values?